# Available alternative DNS protocol not another dark-net

Tags: privacy, dns, p2p

Hi does any one knows any DNS alternative Protocols ?

If so what is the most used ?

Is easy to setup ?

Is easy to have two DNS protocols one where you connect to the Common Internet and the other to the 'Inernet 2.0' ?

**EDIT I mean if is there like a p2p network or something else that is not easy to control by the goverments**

Comment: Are you looking for a different name resolution protocol? Or are you looking for an better way to use DNS. Explaining why you can't use DNS would help.

Comment: differnet name resolution protocol that is more anonymous

Comment: Hi @jkarr, there isn't really a question here... and even if you were to clarify it somehow, it is not a security issue, and as such would not be on topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If DNS performs the appropriate function, then why look for an alternate protocol? Just use DNS.

You can, if you want, use different root servers. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_DNS_root for some of the more popular alternate DNS databases.

Answer (score 2):

I think you really mean you're looking to combine DNS data from different servers rather than different protocols? Most DNS servers allow you to declare records for a local network (and if, say, you define an authoritative record for google.com then clients configured to use only your DNS will see your records).

Or do you mean different DNS servers? There's lots to chose from - you don't mentioned what constraints apply here - are you looking for something to run on a specific OS?

Not clear what you mean by "dark-net" nor internet 2.0, nor what this has to do with security.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to be totally Anonymous on the internet. The following links should give you a lot of information and tools to do so.

https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO

https://www.torproject.org